# magento 2 web rest api - Get all products with a specific attribute code

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I have some products with a custom attribute called "day_special" which may have a value of 'yes' or 'no'. When I called a product (say sku: abc115) through webapi (url: domain.com/rest/V1/products/abc115), It shows all the  product details and the "day_special" attribute is there within the "custom_attributes" section and values in it.

Now I want to get all the products with a specific custom attribute. That is get all products with attributes "day_special" as "yes". Is there any rest api method which gives the mentioned results?

Answer (score 4):

You can try using the `catalogProductRepositoryV1` -> `[GET] /V1/products`

```
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]
```

So the final URL will look like this:

```
http://<magento_host>/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=custom_attribute_code&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=custom_attribute_value&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq
```

References:
http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/